# React-quilljs: Getting Initial Value From useEffect

Tags: reactjs, axios, quill, react-state, react-quill

I'm working with [react-quilljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-quilljs) See the docs where it goes into setting up "With Initial Value." Using their docs this works fine until you try to pull an initial value from a database using useEffect. I continuously get the error *TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')* from this line of code below:

`quill.clipboard.dangerouslyPasteHTML(savedIntroText);`

**Any idea how to correctly go about this?**

```
  const [savedIntroText, setSavedIntroText] = useState();

// Getting text in from database
    useEffect(() => {
      const fetchResults = async () => {
        const result = await axios({
          method: "GET",
          url: "http://localhost:4000/userData",
          withCredentials: true,
        });
        setSavedIntroText(result.data.introEssayText);
      };
      fetchResults();
    }, []);
    
    //Setting initial Quill value here, as shown in docs:
    if (quill) {
      quill.clipboard.dangerouslyPasteHTML(savedIntroText);
    }
    
    const handleUpdatedIntro = () => {
      const text = quill.getText();
      setSavedIntroText(text);
    };
    
    // ===== Implementing Quill ======
    
    <div ref={quillRef} onInput={handleUpdatedIntro} />;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your current code, `quill.clipboard.dangerouslyPasteHTML(savedIntroText);` is called before any value is set for `savedIntroText` (thus the undefined error you are seeing). If you would like the value to be pasted once retrieved by the API try moving it into your `useEffect`, after the data is loaded, e.g.:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchResults = async () => {
    // Only request/load data once quill is loaded
    if (!quill) {
      return;
    }
    const result = await axios({
      method: "GET",
      url: "http://localhost:4000/userData",
      withCredentials: true,
    });
    quill.clipboard.dangerouslyPasteHTML(result.data.introEssayText);
  };
  fetchResults();
}, [quill]);
```

Comment: This solves the undefined error, however this does not work because quill does not load before this runs. Any idea how to get around that problem?

Comment: Looking at the docs, it appears that `quill` will be undefined initially. I've updated the example to handle this by adding `quill` to the `useEffect` dependencies and only requesting/loading the data once `quill` is loaded.